# Priority in TestNG with multiple classes

Tags: testng

I'm facing with the following problem: I created two classes which include @Tests with priority attribute:

```
@Test( priority = 1 )
public void testA1() {
    System.out.println("testA1");
}

@Test( priority = 2 )
public void testA2() {
    System.out.println("testA2");
}

@Test( priority = 3 )
public void testA3() {
    System.out.println("testA3");
}
```

... and ...

```
@Test( priority = 1 )
public void testB1() {
    System.out.println("testB1");
}

@Test( priority = 2 )
public void testB2() {
    System.out.println("testB2");
}

@Test( priority = 3 )
public void testB3() {
    System.out.println("testB3");
}
```

I put both classes under one test in testng.xml but when I run the test, it will order my @Tests based  on the priorities from both classes:

```
testA1
testB1
testA2
testB2
testA3
testB3
```

I'm expecting the following result:

```
testA1
testA2
testA3
testB1
testB2
testB3
```

My question is that how can I prevent to order my @Tests based on both classes and run @Tests only from one class at the same time?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In your suite xml use  group-by-instances="true"

Sample, where TestClass1 and TestClass2 has the same content as yours

```
<suite thread-count="2" verbose="10" name="testSuite" parallel="tests">
<test verbose="2" name="MytestCase" group-by-instances="true">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.crazytests.dataproviderissue.TestClass1" />
        <class name="com.crazytests.dataproviderissue.TestClass2" />
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

I get the output

testA1

testA2

testA3

testB1

testB2

testB3

Comment: Thank you, it works fine for me in my example code too :) But do you know maybe how to pass this parameter to testng.xml programatically? I tried "setGroupByInstances(true)" but it didn't work.

Comment: I don't have an xml... how to set this in Java?

Comment: To peetya: I think it's important to set setGroupByInstances(true) in right place ... as in example, it is in "Test" element, so:  
XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
test.setGroupByInstances(true);

Comment: Hi This is not working for me, Please help. In class A , I have 2 @Test priority 1 and priority 2. On the other hand In class B, I have 3 Test priority 1, 2 and 3 . while running through testng.xml it executes Class A, Priority 1 then jump to Class B Priority 1

Answer (score 1):

You can just provide `@Test(testName="test1") / @Test(testName="test2")` at the top of each class, and the priorities will be automatically grouped per class. Of course you keep the existing annotations.

Comment: Can you give testng.xml for it ? One example

Comment: @Sagar007 I haven't used testng.xml at all

Comment: But I want to run with testng xml. Is that possible ? I have 3 class and I want to give sequence.

Comment: @Sagar007 So I guess the answer has been provided by Sachin Francis

Answer (score 1):

The most correct way is to use dependsOnMethods. 
Priority levels are global for test (don't mix with test-methods which are annotated with @Test). In other words:
when testng runs test (from `<test>` tag) it groups methods by priorities and then run it. In your case both testA1 and testB1 have priority=1, so will be executed at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

you should change the priority on B test
to be like this

```
    @Test( priority = 4 )
    public void testB1() {
        System.out.println("testB1");
    }

    @Test( priority = 5 )
    public void testB2() {
        System.out.println("testB2");
    }

    @Test( priority = 6 )
    public void testB3() {
        System.out.println("testB3");
    }
```

and no changes for XML because it runs as priority

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've separated classes into different tests in testng.xml file and priorities worked as in earlier versions used to.

```
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1">
<test name="TVS_AUTO_TESTS 1">
    <classes>
        <class name="TVS_auto_tests.CheckLoginTests"/>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="TVS_AUTO_TESTS 2">
    <classes>
        <class name="TVS_auto_tests.PageNavigationTests"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

Answer (score 0):

Group the test methods of first class and put dependsOnGroups in test methods of 2nd class.So execution will be proper as per the expectation shown below

ClassOne is as follows

```
    @Test( priority = 1,groups="FirstClass" )
    public void testA1() {
        System.out.println("testA1");
    }

    @Test( priority = 2,groups="FirstClass" )
    public void testA2() {
        System.out.println("testA2");
    }

    @Test( priority = 3,groups="FirstClass" )
    public void testA3() {
        System.out.println("testA3");
    }
```

ClassTwo is as follows

```
    @Test( priority = 1,dependsOnGroups="FirstClass")
    public void testB1() {
        System.out.println("testB1");
    }

    @Test( priority = 2,dependsOnGroups="FirstClass" )
    public void testB2() {
        System.out.println("testB2");
    }

    @Test( priority = 3,dependsOnGroups="FirstClass" )
    public void testB3() {
        System.out.println("testB3");
    }
```

And Finally testng.xml is

```
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="TestCMD.ClassOne"/>
      <class name="TestCMD.ClassTwo"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

It gives the same output as per priority given in both the classes and order also