# How to run testNG methods from different classes in Sequential order

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Ok, I have multiple classes in my testNG suite and all the methods inside those classes has the priority defined. When I run the single class, all the methods runs in a order defined as per the priority but when I run multiple classes, testNG doesn't run it in sequential order. First, it'll run single method from Class A then it'll run another method from Class B and then another method from Class C.

I want testNG to run all the methods from Class A and then move to other classes and run all the methods from those classes before moving to other class. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Ok, so when I removed the priority annotation from all the methods, testNG then executed the methods from all class sequentially but is there any other way to run the methods from different class sequentially with priority ON ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26632241/priority-in-testng-with-multiple-classes) should cover how to retain the order specified for classes while you use priority.