# Selenium/testNG: How to run your test based on class priority and not on your method priorily from the XML file

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

If have the following:

```python
Class A
{ 
  Method M(priority = 2)
}

Class B
{ 
  Method M(priority = 1)
}
```

Then `Class B` is going to be executed before `Class A`. How can I execute `Class A` first?

The XML file that I am using is:

```xml
<classes>
  <class name="com.Users.Admin_ManageUsers_AR"/>
  <class name="com.Users.Admin_ManageUsers_AR"/>
</classes>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Priority in TestNG with multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26632241/priority-in-testng-with-multiple-classes)

Comment: Best practice is to have each test be independent of the others so being able to run them in any order should be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Use `group-by-instances="true"` inside test tag of the testng.xml 
Define your xml like below:

```
<test name="ManageUsersTest" group-by-instances="true">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.Users.Admin_ManageUsers_AR.ClassA" />
        <class name="com.Users.Admin_ManageUsers_AR.ClassB" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with `group-by-instances` as well as answered by others.

Alternatively, you could use groups and dependencies like this [example](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods) in the documentation

```
<test name="ManageUsersTest">
  <groups>
    <dependencies>
      <group name="c" depends-on="a  b" />
      <group name="z" depends-on="c" />
    </dependencies>
  </groups>
</test>
```

The `depends-on` attribute contains a space-separated list of groups.

This gives you more control in case you have dependencies across classes.

Answer (score 0):

An implicit way to prioritise test class execution is to add an alphabetically ordered prefix in class names.  Like, you have test classes named : login , checkout, logout. 
Then rename them as TC01_login , TC02_checkout , TC03_logout. This will automatically prioritise the test execution as per the TC_{serial_number}

Answer (score 0):

Use preserver-order in testng.xml file, then all classes will be executed in order provided in testng.xml

```
<test name="Regression" preserve-order="true">
<classes>
```