# How to preserve order in testng where dependant tests belong to different classes

Tags: java, testng, testng-eclipse

I have total 6 groups where individual group is not depending on anything else but group b depends on group a, group e depends on group b etc.

I want to run test cases according to order which i have mentioned in classes tags. Each class priority starts from 1 .

Mentioned preserve-order="true" in test tag but current behavior is : "first it runs all priority "1" test cases of all files then move to 2nd priority test cases from all files etc. Whereas I want to take  "AA" class and run all test cases depending on priorities then it should jump on "AB" class and so on...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suites" parallel="tests" thread-count="2"
    verbose="1">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="testBase.ListenerClasses" />
    </listeners>
    <test name="Manage Tests" preserve-order="true">
         <groups>
                <run>
                <include name="individual"/>
                    <include name="a" />
                    <include name="b"/>
                <include name="c" />
                    <include name="d" />
                    <include name="e"/>

             </run>
         </groups> 
    <packages>
         <package name="basicTest" /> 
    </packages>

    <classes>
            <class name="AA"></class>
        <class name="AB"></class>
            <class name="AC"></class>
        <class name="AD"></class>
            <class name="AE"></class>
        <class name="AF"></class>
        <class name="AG"></class>
        <class name="AH"></class>
        <class name="AI"></class>
        <class name="AJ"></class>
        <class name="AK"></class>
        <class name="AL"></class>
        <class name="AM"></class> 
        <class name="AN"></class>
        <class name="AO"></class>
        <class name="AP"></class>
        <class name="AQ"></class>
        <class name="AR"></class> 
    </classes>  
    </test>             
</suite>
```

EXPECTED : RUN ALL CLASSES SEQUENTIALLY STARTING FROM AA TO AR WHERE IN AA ALL PRIORITIES STARTING FROM 1 TO 6 COMPLETED THEN IT SHOULD MOVE FOR AB CLASS AND RUN CASES STARTING FROM PRIORITY 1 TO 4 etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your `testng.xml` add `group-by-instances="true"`  like below and it should work

```
 <test name="Manage Tests" preserve-order="true" group-by-instances="true">
```

As described  in  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26632241/priority-in-testng-with-multiple-classes) post

Also have a look at [test groups](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups) and [group-by-instances](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods)