# I need to update testcase result using gurock api

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, mstest, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have written code for creating a `TestRun` in a selected `Milestone` and then the testrun includes the testcase ids which needs to be updated when testcases are executed.How can I do that using Gurock api?

Comment: Does this question on SO help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26632241/priority-in-testng-with-multiple-classes