# How to prioritize classes which is defined in different test in TestngXML?

Tags: java, selenium, testng, testng.xml

My Scenario is like, i need to executed testcases in the following order:
Test A, Test C
Test B.
I need to achieve this via Prioritization in TestNG or if there is any other way please suggest me?
Have attached screenshot for your reference.
[image]

Comment: it is answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26632241/priority-in-testng-with-multiple-classes

Comment: Just to ensure that I understand your problem statement.. Are you looking for enforcing an order amongst test classes that belong to different `<test>` tags ?